# Team Foundation Server 2012 Build Definition to build all solutions in team project

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm setting up a TFS 2012 and want to configure a Build Definition for one of our Team Projects.

What I want to achieve is that I'm able to trigger the Build Definition manually and it should build all Solutions contained in the Team Project.

So far I could include all Solutions at "Process -> 1. required -> Items to build" but then if someone checks-in a new solution to the Team Project I would have to add it manually to the required items.

Is there a way to configure it the way that it automatically builds all solutions in the Team Project?

I read a lot of different posts and blogs saying something about using continuous integration but then I still had to provide required items. Now I'm little bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answear is no, you cant do that out of box, CI will trigger build whenever something changes in defined workspace, it however will build defined solutions/projects.

You will need to create a custom activity for build that will scan your workspace for solutions and override the default list.

This however is bad approach in general - you will have lots of complications - what configuration and platform to build solutions, what if one solution should be excluded, what if solution references assmeblies on host level and buildmachine doesnt have it installed.

More preferred would be to organize your projects into one build solution that builds all the contents (can you have solution of solutions ?) and ensure that your guidlines require to update this build solution when new stuff is added.